# Any initial infinite ordinal is of the form $\omega_{\alpha}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let $\gamma$ be an initial infinite ordinal. Show that $\gamma=\omega_{\alpha}$ for some ordinal $\alpha$

The definition I use for $\omega_{\alpha}$ as follows: 
Suppose $\omega_{\beta},\aleph_{\beta}$ have been defined for all $\beta<\alpha$. By transfinite induction, we define $$\omega_{\alpha}=\{\gamma \ \text{is ordinal}  : |\gamma|\le\aleph_{\beta} \ \text{for some} \ \beta<\alpha\}$$

Comment: I would say that is by definition. What is your definition of "$\omega_\alpha$"?

Comment: @Henning Makholm, I have edited my question :)